# Find matching values across multiple columns using VBA with Excel

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Before Code Execution]

[image: After Code Execution]

I have VBA code as shown below within excel that allows me to label rows that have the word "FALSE" in one or more columns as shown in the images. How do i get the code to loop only the number of times the product of the rows and columns,in this case 25 (5 rows * 5 Columns) and exit without using a For loop.

```
Dim myRange As Range

Dim Rc As Long
Dim Cc As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set myRange = Range("C12:G16")

Rc = myRange.Rows.Count
Cc = myRange.Columns.Count
iter = Rc * Cc


With Worksheets(1).Range("C12:G16")
Set c = .Find("False", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
firstAddress = c.Address
Do
i = Cc - c.Column + 2
c.Select
Selection.Offset(0, i) = "FALSE"

Set c = .FindNext(c)
Loop While Not c Is Nothing

End If
End With
```

Comment: A `For` loop sounds like just the thing you need. Why refuse to use the proper tool? It's like asking someone to nail something to a wall without a hammer.

Comment: When you know exactly how many iterations you're going to need before you start looping, you use a `For` loop.

Comment: Are there only 4 columns of data? If so, you could also accomplish this with a worksheet function. `=IFERROR(FIND("false",LOWER(B1))>0,0)` will determine if cell B1 contains "False" and then you can use a bunch of these within the `OR()` function to check if any of the 4 cells in a row contain "False". Let me know if this sounds like it could work for you.

Comment: If range is selected dynamically,  the range properties myRange.Rows.Count and myRange.Column.Count does not  seem to work using the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This will select your entire used range dynamically, then populate "False" for each row in the first column to the right of your used range if False exists a that row.

```
Sub LabelRowsFalse()

Dim myRng As Range
Dim rngWidth As Integer
Dim nextCol As Integer
Dim rngCol As Integer

Set myRng = Sheet1.UsedRange
rngWidth = myRng.Columns.Count
rngCol = myRng.Column

With myRng
    Set c = .Find("False", LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Cells(c.Row, (rngWidth + rngCol)).Value = "False"
        Set c = .FindNext(c)

        While c.Address <> firstAddress
            Cells(c.Row, (rngWidth + rngCol)).Value = "False"
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Wend

    End If
End With

MsgBox ("done")

End Sub
```

Comment: What if the range is selected dynamically?

Comment: @Buzoka - I've updated it to select your entire used range dynamically, then write to the first column after your used range.  If you want to set the range to something other than your entire used range, you can do that with line 8.  If you do that, you'll also need to edit your target column (rngWidth + rngCol) in lines 15 & 19.